# Concept of Tarjan's bridge-finding algorithm

Tags: algorithm, graph

I was doning a problem of finding a bridge in a undirected connected graph, I looked up wikipedia for Tarjan's algorithm. Here is what it writes

> **Tarjan's bridge-finding algorithm**
> The first linear time algorithm for finding the bridges in a graph was described by
> Robert Tarjan in 1974. It performs the following steps:
>
> - Find a spanning forest of G
> - Create a rooted forest F from the spanning forest
> - Traverse the forest F in preorder and number the nodes. Parent nodes in the forest now have lower numbers than child nodes.
> - For each node v in preorder (denoting each node using its preorder number), do:
>
>   - Compute the number of forest descendants ND(v) for this node, by adding one to the sum of its children's descendants.
>   - Compute L(v), the lowest preorder label reachable from v by a path for which all but the last edge stays within
>     the subtree rooted at v. This is the minimum of the set
>     consisting of the preorder label of v, of the values of
>     L(w) at child nodes of v and of the preorder
>     labels of nodes reachable from v by edges that do not
>     belong to F.
>   - Similarly, compute H(v), the highest preorder label reachable by a path for which all but the last edge stays within the
>     subtree rooted at v. This is the maximum of the set
>     consisting of the preorder label of v, of the values of
>     H(w) at child nodes of v and of the preorder
>     labels of nodes reachable from v by edges that do not
>     belong to F.
>   - For each node w with parent node v, if L(w) = w and H(w) <  w + ND(w) then the edge
>     from v to w is a bridge.

I wonder whether I understand the previous steps wrong, since in my opinion, I think that L(w) = w is never gonna happen except at the root. Where in other cases, L(w) should be at least smaller than the father of w.

[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_(graph_theory))

Answer (score 0):

The English description of L and H is slightly wrong -- they should exclude paths that contain the parent edge, or else it's as if there are parallel edges between each pair of adjacent nodes, hence no bridges. The algorithm for computing L and H correctly iterates over children only.